# Find the difference between previous row and current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `presenters`

[image]

I want to find the difference between presenters salary. Like (Jason - Vicki, Jason - Tiff, Vicki - Tiff).

I have the following code

```
SELECT 
    P2.PNRFNAME, P1.PNRFNAME AS "pnrfname",
    P2.SALARY_YEARLY - P1.SALARY_YEARLY AS "salary difference" 
FROM 
    PRESENTERS P2
JOIN 
    PRESENTERS P1 ON P2.PNRFNAME > P1.PNRFNAME
ORDER BY 
    "salary difference"
```

These are the results

[image]

But I want the following results

[image]

Comment: Use `LAG()` instead.  Much more efficient than a self-join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your row are ordered by `PRESENTERID`, instead of doing `P2.PNRFNAME > P1.PNRFNAME` you can use `PRESENTERID`.

Try;

```
SELECT P2.PNRFNAME ,P1.PNRFNAME AS "pnrfname" , P2.SALARY_YEARLY - P1.SALARY_YEARLY AS "salary difference" 
FROM PRESENTERS P2
INNER JOIN PRESENTERS P1
ON P2.PRESENTERID> P1.PRESENTERID
ORDER BY P2.PRESENTERID, P1.PRESENTERID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY PNRFNAME
            )
        ,PNRFNAME
        ,SALARY_YEARLY
    FROM PRESENTERS
    )
SELECT prev.PNRFNAME PreviousValue
    ,CTE.PNRFNAME
    ,prev.SALARY_YEARLY - CTE.SALARY_YEARLY AS SALARY_DIFF
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN CTE prev ON prev.rownum = CTE.rownum - 1
GO
```

Source: [How to Access the Previous Row and Next Row value in SELECT statement?](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/)